# Django: What's the difference between overriding the create() method and the save method()?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to override some model behavior, but am unsure where I should do it.

If I understand this right, the `create()` method is just a wrapper for the `save()` method. I've seen examples of overriding behavior...

1. [in the create() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects),
2. [in the save() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) before calling the real save() method,
3. [and in the save() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) after calling the real save() method.

What's the difference?

---

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, name):
        blog = cls(name=name)
        # do something <-- 1!
        return blog

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do_something <-- 2!
        super(Blog, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.
        # do_something_else <-- 3!
```

Comment: The `save` method is on the model, but the `create` method is the default manager creating the object for you, which does some validations, and in turn call the save method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example (from Django documentation) create() is *not* overriden. There is no such method in Model class.

There is a create method in ModelManager (queries): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.create

In overrideen save method, only if you change object before calling super().save(), changes will be saved. After super().save(), it is mostly about feedback. But if you raise an exception here, the save will be rolled back. Also, you may want to catch an Exception from super().save() and do something about it.